# Should Project Management be merged into the new Workplace StackExchange site?

Tags: discussion

This site is only getting a few questions a day - would a merger be a good idea?

Alternately, what about merging in Product Management or IT Management?  (The former is only at proposal stage).

Answer (score 5):

No. This site has unique project management related content and it has been growing steadily over the course of the beta. The content is increasingly coming up in search results and visits are growing.  I think it takes time (like most projects : ) ).

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of examples of other Stack Exchange sites that are in beta for over a year. Many of them are close to meeting their graduation criteria, many are not.

As long as the sites continue to show signs of growth, there is no reason to justify calling them dead.

Additionally, the Workplace SE site was created in response to many closed questions on Programmers SE. The questions asked on Workplace SE may or may not have anything to do with Project Management and may actually draw an entirely different crowd.

Currently, PMSE receives over 1,105 visits per day, which is the most visits it has ever received per day since launch. If you look at the other [Area51 PMSE Metrics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947/project-management), it's clear we're doing well in every area except for questions per day.

As we continue to draw more expert and enthusiast project managers, and as we continue to encourage great, detailed questions and well-constructed answers, we'll see this metric increase to the point where graduation is imminent. We're not at that point yet, but we're steadily and methodically marching to that point.

Comment: Added alternatives to boost traffic.

Comment: There have been discussions about merging IT Management with Project Management, but that was early on. At this point, I think the same problem would arise in that this site has already built a community around one topic, and merging into a site with a year's worth of questions may fundamentally and irrevocably change it.